# operator precedence order and evaluation confusion

Tags: c++, c, operators, operator-precedence

In the books and [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) its given that the precedence of increment & decrement operator is more than the ternary operator but then why in the code below, the values of both b and c in not incrementing but only b is incrementing (or c is incrementing is condition is false)

```
int a=1,h;
h = (a==1)?++b:++c;
printf("%d%d",b,c);
```

or even for the statements like

```
++i&&++j||++k;   // why not all the increment and decrement operator executes first
```

please explain if I am making some conceptual mistake and sorry for being too noob
(if this is a duplicate then please redirect me to original question, I didn't found one)

Comment: Well, I hope this confusion serves as a strong deterrent against writing code like this.

Comment: Oh, "too localized", where have you gone? :(

Comment: @sumitb Do you have a clear understanding of what a ternary operator does ?

Comment: two words: LAZY EVALUATION.

Comment: If the author of this code worked for me, I would apply the 'pink slip' deterrent.

Answer (score 4):

The conditional (`?:`), logical conjunction (`&&`), and logical disjunction (`||`) operators are lazy<sup>†</sup>. They only evaluate the operands necessary to produce a result.

In the case of the conditional operator, it only evaluates one of the two branches; the first one if the condition evaluates to true, or the second one if the condition evaluates to false.

The logical conjuntion operator will not evaluate the right hand side expression if the left hand side expression evaluates to false, because the result will be false no matter what. The logical disjuntion operator operates in similar fashion, with the difference that it will not evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side evalutes to true: `true || x` is always true, regardless of `x`.

---

<sup>†</sup> Unless you are dealing with overloaded `&&` or `||`. Overloaded operators cannot perform lazy evaluation of the operands.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour that never happens. It never evaluates the two branches.

Comment: Ah. The conditional operator cannot be overloaded, so that wouldn't apply. I'll reword it.

Comment: +1 That is perfectly clear now.

Answer (score 2):

For `h = (a==1)?++b:++c;` see *C11 6.5.15 Conditional operator p4* (my emphasis

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its
>   evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated). **The second operand is evaluated only if the
>   first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0**;

This confirms that your observation that only one of `++b` and `++c` are executed is correct.

For `++i&&++j||++k;` see C11 sections 6.5.13, 6.5.14.  Both the logical OR and AND operators evaluate left to right, skipping evaluation of further expressions once the result is known (so, once an expression evaluates to non-zero for `||`; once an expression evaluates to zero for `&&`).

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator evaluates only the condition operand and the operand that happens to be true. The `++c` part in your case is not evaluated at all.

In the second case, not all of the operands are evaluated because the `||` and `&&` operators do what is called "short-circuiting", that is, if the whole expression doesn't have a chance to change its result anymore, the rest of the operands are not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

**Precedence does not control order of evaluation.**.  It only controls how operators and operands are grouped together.

Both the `||` and `&&` operators force left-to-right evaluation, and both are "short-circuit" operators; if the value of the expression can be determined from the left-hand expression, then the right-hand expression won't be evaluated at all.

So given an expression like

```
a++ || b++ && c++
```

if the result of `a++` is non-zero, then the result will be true regardless of the result of `b++ && c++`, so the right-hand side is not evaluated at all.